# Ctrl + arrow keys working in tmux

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

When I SSH in to our server, control + arrow sequences are working fine for me: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd> gives `^[OA`, `^[OB`, `^[OC`, and `^[OD` respectively. In tmux, I get `^[[A`, `^[[B`, `^[[C`, and `^[[D`.

I'm connecting to Ubuntu via PuTTY, *but*…

- I have the correct terminal set (`putty` because `ncurses-term` is installed). All other key combinations are working in the main shell.
- I'm using the right character set (UTF-8).
- I'm definitely getting a 256-colour terminal (I've tried multiple invocations of `TERM=... tmux`)
- I've read the tmux FAQs that say to use this config:

  ```
   set -g terminal-overrides "xterm*:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:smkx@:rmkx@"
  ```

making my config like so:

```
    set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
    set -g terminal-overrides "screen*:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:smkx@:rmkx@"
    set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

since `screen` was recommended elsewhere (though I tried `putty` there, too.

The only thing I've found that worked is running `tput rmkx` within `tmux`, but I don't know if that's the correct solution, what other effects it has, if other programs will change this setting, or even how it should be set correctly in `.tmux.conf` so that I don't have to type it in manually all the time.

Comment: What version of tmux is this?

Comment: v1.8 (now i'm dealing with [this problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255210/161288))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to *[How to enable Control key combinations for GNU screen on putty?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139744/how-to-enable-control-key-combinations-for-gnu-screen-on-putty/281170#281170)*, but addresses a different aspect.

In a quick check, it seems that the problem is a conflict between this line

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

and this:

```
set -g terminal-overrides "screen*:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:smkx@:rmkx@"
```

Dropping the `set-window-option` makes your configuration work for me.

Comment: I exited all tmux sessions, commented out the `xterm-keys` option with a `#`, a created a new tmux session and no change.

Comment: Doing the above and using `set -g terminal-overrides "putty*:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:smkx@:rmkx@"` worked. (Answer edit to show that correction was rejected.)

Answer (score 3):

I now no longer use `terminal-overrides` nor PuTTY at all. My relevant `.tmux.conf` is this:

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

I use [KiTTY](https://www.9bis.net/kitty/) for my terminal emulator, and, where possible, compile a [KiTTY-specific terminfo file](https://github.com/creidhne-a16i/kitty-terminfo), otherwise use `putty-256color` as the terminal type.

Comment: With kitty it is working for me. Thanks.