# tmux on remote machine not getting correct prefix + arrow keys

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I am connecting from a windows machine to a remote machine using MobaXterm,  and attach to a tmux session. Some key are not getting sent correctly, for example prefix + arrow keys just prints {A,B,C,D} when I press prefix+{up,down,right,left}, when these keys should navigate between tmux panes. 
If I use Putty (instead of MobaXterm), I can fix this by using 'linux' terminal instead of 'xterm', but in MobaXterm the terminal types I can choose are xterm, xterm-r6, vt100, vt220, and vt900. None of them work.

I guess some of the problem is the remote machine itself (which runs Ubuntu 16.04), because other remote machines do not have this problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which remote machines work?  Your question is a variant of [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288871/ctrl-arrow-keys-working-in-tmux).

Comment: The remote machine that works runs Red Hat 6.7. I've tried the suggestion in the question you linked to - but it doesn't work.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to pinpoint the problem (I'm short of time, can look more this evening).  The "xterm" description on both should be the same (your `TERM` variable may differ, there may be tmux conf-file differences, etc).

Comment: I'd appreciate any further suggestions. The TERM var is the same ('screen-256color' as defined the .tmux.conf file), and I use the same .tmux.conf file.

Answer (score 2):

There are unrelated differences between Red Hat 6 and Ubuntu 16 for the `screen-256color` entry: the latter adds `dim` and omits `initc`.  Neither of those changes is related to cursor-keys.

Presumably the value of `TERM` *outside* `tmux` is `xterm`.  There are also unrelated changes between the two systems for the `xterm` entry (the [cursor color extensions](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_X_T_E_R_M__Extensions_) mentioned in the terminal database).

However, there is a significant difference between the `linux` and `xterm` entries: the `xterm` entries (in both cases) initialize the terminal to use *application mode* for cursor- and keypad-keys, while that for `linux` does not.  Application mode sends different character sequences for the cursor-keys (which is the point of this question).

Red Hat 6 has tmux 1.6, Ubuntu 16 has tmux 2.3.  In either case, `tmux` reads the terminal description and *tries* to match the escape sequences sent by your *outside* terminal's cursor- and function-keys, and stores its notion of those keys (as a keycode and shift/control information) before *generating* an equivalent escape sequence which follows the terminal description *inside* `tmux`.

If your `.tmux.conf` file had conflicting settings as shown in *[Ctrl + arrow keys working in tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288871/ctrl-arrow-keys-working-in-tmux)*, then the rather old and rather new `tmux` programs will differ for modified cursor-keys:

- in CentOS6, shifted uparrow gives `^[[A^[[1;2A`, while Ubuntu shows `^[[A`.
- control-uparrow also differs.

The reason for the difference is (actually) an improvement in `tmux`, to read the *extended* key definitions from the terminal database.  In the older version, `tmux` did not notice that the xterm-style keys were not defined in the `screen-256color` terminal description.  So it passed the information on.  In the newer version, `tmux` sees that they are not defined, and (because it was told to be aware of xterm-keys), uses only those that *are* defined in the specified terminal description.

Further reading:

- [My cursor keys do not work](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#cursor_appmode)

Comment: The `TERM` value outside tmux is indeed `xterm`. Regarding version, on the Red Hat system I use a locally compiled version 2.2 (since I don't have root on this system), on the Ubuntu a version I installed with apt-get, which is 2.1

Answer (score 0):

It could be a conflicting prefix key, so you could try changing this. Tmux allows for this, and you can make it persist by creating a `~/.tmux.conf` file.

The line to add to the conf file would be something like this:

```
set-option -g prefix M-a
```

Which would change your prefix key to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

If you don't want these changes to persist, you can just run that line as a command from within tmux.

Here's a little about the correct syntax for this (taken from the man page):

```
KEY BINDINGS
    tmux allows a command to be bound to most keys, with or without a prefix key.  When specifying keys, most represent them-
     selves (for example ‘A’ to ‘Z’).  Ctrl keys may be prefixed with ‘C-’ or ‘^’, and Alt (meta) with ‘M-’.  In addition, the
     following special key names are accepted: Up, Down, Left, Right, BSpace, BTab, DC (Delete), End, Enter, Escape, F1 to F12,
     Home, IC (Insert), NPage/PageDown/PgDn, PPage/PageUp/PgUp, Space, and Tab.  Note that to bind the ‘"’ or ‘'’ keys, quotation
     marks are necessary, for example:
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but with no success. I need to mention that prefix + {h,j,k,l} for selecting pane works as it should. It is the arrow keys which do not work. Actually I noticed it sometimes work, sometimes just prints `A`, and sometimes prints `[A` (or B or C or D, depending on the arrow key used)