# How to get the F1-F4 keys to behave normally in tmux

Tags: terminal, tmux, putty

In my normal terminal, <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> keys produce `^[[11~^[[12~^[[13~^[[14~`, but in tmux I get `^[OP^[OQ^[OR^[OS`. I'd like them to behave the same in tmux so I don't have muck around with bindings for programs in tmux. I don't have PuTTY's *Xterm R6* option on.

I'm using `putty-256color` as my terminal type both from putty and in tmux to get around other keys being mismatched, though I still have to remap my arrow keys.

Config <del>is</del> was:

```
set -g default-terminal "putty-256color"
set -g terminal-overrides "putty*:smkx@:rmkx@:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:kf1=\e[11~:kf2=\e[12~:kf3=\e[13~:kf4=\e[14~"
```

The rest of my config is unrelated cosmetic stuff. You can see I've tried to remap the 4 function keys back to original, but I haven't got it to work.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental, why can't my keys stay the same for *every* key inside and outside tmux, with the exception of **prefix** so these issues do not occur?

**Edit**
My problem still exists but I *was* missing something fundamental: `default-terminal` refers to the terminal type *within* tmux but `terminal-overrides` refers to the term type I'm connecting with, i.e. *outside* of tmux. (Yes, I feel stupid.)

My config is now like so:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -g terminal-overrides "putty*:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:kf1=\e[11~:kf2=\e[12~:kf3=\e[13~:kf4=\e[14~:smkx@:rmkx@"
```

<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> still give me `^[[11~^[[12~^[[13~^[[14~` outside of tmux, and `^[OP^[OQ^[OR^[OS` inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual page is not clear, but reading the source code helps:

- take a look at [input-keys.c](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/input-keys.c#L44), and you will see the keys, listed in a table.
- the table is used in the same file, in [`input_key`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/input-keys.c#L152)
- [near the top](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/input-keys.c#L152) of the file, there's a comment:

```
    /*
     * This file is rather misleadingly named, it contains the code which takes a
     * key code and translates it into something suitable to be sent to the
     * application running in a pane (similar to input.c does in the other
     * direction with output).
     */
```

Your shell is the application that the comment refers to.

The `terminal-overrides` is used to modify the terminal description which `tmux` reads, to allow you to work with configurations (of the external "real" terminal) which do not match the terminal description:

- the terminal description is read from [tty_term_find](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/tty-term.c#L384),
- which then applies the overrides via [tty_term_override](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/tty-term.c#L300)

`tmux` translates keys into its own set of escape sequences (matching the ones in `screen`, with the exception that it adds the `xterm-keys` option).  The [comment at the top of `window.c`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/window.c#L39) summarizes this:

```
 * A pane has two buffers attached, these are filled and emptied by the main
 * server poll loop. Output data is received from pty's in screen format,
 * translated and returned as a series of escape sequences and strings via
 * input_parse (in input.c). Input data is received as key codes and written
 * directly via input_key.
```

The [manual page](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1) says

> **`default-terminal`** *terminal*
>   Set the default terminal for new windows created in this session - the default value of the **`TERM`** environment variable. For `tmux` to work correctly, this ***must*** be set to *‘screen’*, *‘tmux’* or a derivative of them.

The reason for the restriction is that there's no way to customize the data in `input-keys.c` in the way you would like.

Comment: Thanks for your help but now I'm back to where I started, using `screen` conjures up [this issue](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/288871/161288) (which you helped with). Using the config `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` and `set -g terminal-overrides "screen*:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:smkx@:rmkx@"` does not restore the arrow key sequences that work when I use `putty` in place of `screen`.

Comment: Do I need some lengthy set of `send-keys` commands in my `.tmux.conf`?

Comment: I suppose you could do it that way, but it seems awkward...

Comment: It does, but how else can I remap keys before they ever get to the program inside tmux?

Comment: Only by modifying tmux, or a workaround such as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The keycode of your function keys must mach the keycode of your terminal definition.

I mean if your F1 function key produce ^[[11~ you must have kf1=\E[11~ (e.g. TERM=dtterm) in the definition of your terminal.

If your F1 function key produce ^[OP you must have kf1=\EOP (e.g. TERM=vt220) in the definition of your terminal.

You can check the key assignment of your terminal with the *infocmp* command.

Comment: I already have those in the `set -g terminal-overrides`. Those keys still don't have the same output in and out of tmux, but Vim, etc. understand them, so I guess it's meant to be that way.